# How can I cut a part of a string from the right and return it?

Tags: php

I have a line like this: `C:\fakepath\Хэнчетт, Листуон. Vue.js в действии 2019.pdf`

How can I write this part of the string to a variable? `Хэнчетт, Листуон. Vue.js в действии 2019.pdf`

Comment: Use `basename()` to get the filename from a path or URL.

Comment: [`pathinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) Can be found in the PHP manual. Splits a path into its constituent parts

Comment: On which operating system is the PHP code running? And that part (component) of a file-system path is called basename as others have commented and it is the last path component.